# gdbserver --> Reply contains invalid character

Tags: c, gdb, gdbserver

I am trying to debug a cross-compiled application with gdbserver. Unfortunately I get the following error on my host:
`Reply contains invalid hex digit 59`
Here's what I did:

- compiled my application "line-generator" (which is just a test program) with gcc -ggdb3 -std=gnu89 flags (using -g instead of -ggdb3 didn't make any difference)
- copy the executable to my embedded system. The exec can be executed there
- started gdbserver 192.168.10.20:54320 line-generator on the embedded system
- On the host I start gdb: gdb line-generator.gdb
- (gdb) target remote 192.168.10.102:54320
- Got this response on host: 
  Remote debugging using 192.168.10.102:54320
  Reply contains invalid hex digit 59
- On the server I got this:
  Remote debugging from host 192.168.10.20
  readchar: Got EOF
  Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
  Listening on port 54320

I have never used gdb remotely so maybe I am running into a beginner's issue so every response might help.

edit: My gdbserver was provided by the manufacturer of the embedded hardware.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934552/cant-remote-debug-with-gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that remote-debugging a cross-compiled executable needs gdb on the host computer to be compiled for this purpuse. In my case it means that I have to use this command

```
/opt/microblaze-uclinux-tools/bin/microblaze-uclinux-gdb line-g
enerator.gdb
```

instead of simple `gdb line-generator.gdb`

Luckily the correct file was provided by the embedded board manufacturer!
To be honest I don't fully understand the context so if someone has an explanation on this I'd be glad to hear this! 
cheers, Stefan